# Can not find 'define-key' function

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs23 installed in ubuntu 10.04

Tried to define a keybinding by using

```
M-x define-key "key" 'function
```

in the mimi buffer, but it told me that "[No Match]"

Tried to put

```
(define-key ctl-x-map "1" 'goto-line)
```

in my .emacs file, still the keybinding is not changed, c-x-l still invoke the 'count lines in page' function.

any clue why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one fails because `M-x` only displays functions that are declared `(interactive)`.  The interactive version of `define-key` is `global-set-key`.

The second one would be because you are defining `C-x 1`, but then trying to use `C-x l`.  `1` and `l` haven't been the same character since typewriters went out of style.

Comment: I was thinking too much about why define-key doesn't work in minibuffer, then completely didn't notice I mistook 1 and l, shame on me ...